# MySQL specific query performance tuning

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have troubles with MySQL query performance.

Table (InnoDB):

```
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field              | Type                | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| st_resource_id     | varchar(32)         | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |
| st_sub_resource_id | varchar(32)         | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| st_title           | varchar(500)        | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| st_resource_type   | varchar(100)        | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |
| st_site_id         | tinyint(4)          | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |
| st_time            | timestamp           | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| st_user_id         | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| st_full_access     | tinyint(1) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

Indexes:

```
+---------------+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name         | Seq_in_index | Column_name        | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------------+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| nr_statistics |          1 | resource_id      |            1 | st_resource_id     | A         |     1546165 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| nr_statistics |          1 | resource_id      |            2 | st_sub_resource_id | A         |     1546165 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| nr_statistics |          1 | st_time          |            1 | st_time            | A         |     1546165 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| nr_statistics |          1 | st_site_id       |            1 | st_site_id         | A         |          16 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| nr_statistics |          1 | st_resource_type |            1 | st_resource_type   | A         |          16 |       10 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+---------------+------------+------------------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT st_resource_id AS docId, count(*) AS cnt
FROM nr_statistics
WHERE
  st_resource_type = 'document'
  AND st_sub_resource_id = 'text'
  AND st_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
  AND st_site_id = 1
GROUP BY st_resource_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 0, 5;
```

Query plan:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys                       | key         | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | nr_statistics | index | st_time,st_site_id,st_resource_type | resource_id | 197     | NULL | 1581044 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+-------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Table has ~1,666,383 rows. The query runs extremely slow. In MySQL process list I see this query in "copy to tmp table phase" for a long time (> 1 minute). Query generates heavy I/O load. I can't understand what to do to fix the problem and speed-up query execution.

If the problem is a result of wrong indexes, so what indexes will be right?

**UPD.** I created new composite index:

```
| nr_statistics |          1 | st_site_id_2     |            1 | st_site_id         | A         |          16 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| nr_statistics |          1 | st_site_id_2     |            2 | st_resource_type   | A         |          16 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| nr_statistics |          1 | st_site_id_2     |            3 | st_sub_resource_id | A         |      752018 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| nr_statistics |          1 | st_site_id_2     |            4 | st_time            | A         |     1504037 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| nr_statistics |          1 | st_site_id_2     |            5 | st_resource_id     | A         |     1504037 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
```

Now query plan is:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | nr_statistics | range | st_site_id_2  | st_site_id_2 | 406     | NULL | 21168 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

The query now runs very fast (as 0.0x sec), but I have to force using new index:

```
SELECT st_resource_id as docId, count( * ) AS Cnt
FROM nr_statistics
USE INDEX (st_site_id_2)
WHERE st_resource_type = 'document'
AND st_sub_resource_id = 'text'
AND st_time > DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 7 DAY )
AND st_site_id = 1
GROUP BY st_resource_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 0 , 5;
```

While the problem is resolved (not beautiful but effective way), I still have some open questions (see comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a composite index on `(st_site_id, st_resource_type, st_sub_resourse_id, st_time, st_resource_id)`.

However, you will still have `temporary` and `filesort` in the plan because you are ordering on `COUNT(*)` which is not indexable.

If you need to run this query fast and often, you would have to create an aggregate table which would store counts for each site/resource/subresourse/week combination and update it in a trigger.

Comment: I've created composite index as you told. But MySQL still doesn't use it. When I forced mysql to use new index query plan changed (see update in my question). But the perfomance got great! Query executes in 0.0xxx seconds. Great thans for that advice.

Why MySQL don't use new index automaticaly?
Why 4 independent indexes can't be used by MySQL? Is it almost the same as one composite?

Comment: @ValeraLeontyev: one composite index is not quite the same as 4 independent ones. 4 indexes do not form a single range where all your records reside. They may be used to improve the query speed (with `index_merge`) but only on equality conditions, and it seems that it's the `st_time` predicate which is most selective for your query.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try creating a composite index on `st_resource_type, st_resource_id, st_time and st_site_id`? It looks to me like you have several indexes, but most are on a single column, or maybe 2 columns. By having a composite index with more of the columns you need, it may improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

When doing queries with multiple where clauses the order in which you write them should match the order in which you wrote your query.

In your particular case it would be:

```
CREATE INDEX stats_index ON nr_statistics (st_resource_type, st_sub_resource_id, st_time, st_site_id);
```

This should give you a pretty good speed boost.